# Reusing matched variable inside of match statement

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, match, borrow-checker, ownership

I'm looking for a good pattern of dealing with this kind of situations. I want to proceed with further operations after checking that given variable is proper type/contains what I expect. Problem is I want to reuse matched variable.

```
fn proceed(stream: std::net::TcpStream) {
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:7878");

    match stream {
       TcpStream => proceed(stream.unwrap()),
       Error => println!("buuuu")
   }
}
```

It gives me `variable used after move` error. Blind-fixing by creating closure with move results in more cascading errors. Is using `match` statement any good in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pattern match on the `Ok` variant of the `Result`:

```rust
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn proceed(stream: TcpStream) {
    todo!()
}

fn example() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:7878");

    match stream {
       Ok(tcp) => proceed(tcp),
       Err(err) => println!("buuuu"),
   }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=338eea6876fad6d04c3877964084a639)

Comment: @Mike79745 if my answer solved your problem please consider upvoting it and accepting it (by clicking the gray checkmark underneath the answer score), thanks!